# Best data structure for point cloud updates?

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm working on a robot using the new jetson nano. I've got points generating from the depth image of my camera and am working towards creating a scene as the robot moves around. My issue is just throwing points into the data structure every frame would make me run out of memory super quickly. Thus I want to have some heuristic that says if a point meets some condition don't add it.

For this I imagine I need an acceleration structure like an Octree, KDTree, BVH Hierarchy, or maybe something else. While I am familiar with them and find lots of info on how to build them, I'm a little confused on which of them would be easiest to update each frame or if some require complete rebuilds compared to incremental rebuilds. Could some be parallelized? Any insight on what type data structure maybe with a link about it would super helpful.

Edit:
I believe the best structure for this is likely a Sparse Voxel Octree. You can find some general ideas of how to do so with this blog from Nvidia. https://devblogs.nvidia.com/thinking-parallel-part-iii-tree-construction-gpu/ .
If a morton code maps to a specific voxel that voxel is 'filled'. Redundant points are automatically taken care of as voxel is either filled or unfilled. For removal I think i can do ray tracing on the octree and if I collide with a filled voxel before I expect too delete the existing voxel. There are some resolution problems, but I think I can handle this with a hybrid approach.

Comment: What makes you decide whether to throw or keep a point ?

Comment: I've actually 'solved' my problem. I'm going to use a Sparse Voxel Octree. Using a 64-bit Morton Code I can get better than millimeter accuracy over a kilometer. I think with a hybrid approach I can probably get good accuracy with a 32-bit morton code also. Then if a point should be kept will be determined by simply does it map to a voxel that currently doesn't exist. To throw them away I'll ray cast from the current position to the currently visible positions deleting any voxels in the way. Still working on it though, imagine this will take me a few days to work out.

Comment: You don't really answer the question. But never mind.

Comment: @YvesDaoust apologies I thought I did. A point maps to a morton code which is a voxel index such as (1,1,1) each voxel has a spacing based on your resolution of let's say 1 cm ^3 but is dynamic based on several parameters. When I get a new input point I calculate this code and mark the voxel as 'filled'. Redundant points are automatically taken care of because marking a voxel that is filled as filled again does not add additional memory. I have added an Nvidia link that covers some of the idea.

Comment: To remove the point I raycast from the current position to all visible positions. If I encounter a position before one that is visible then the voxel is no longer filled so I can 'unfill' that voxel in a second pass.

Comment: You are saying how you remove or add, not why. Smells the XY problem.

Comment: I thought 'how' was the question. The why is I need to add and remove points so the robot has a reasonable virtualization of its environment for planning its navigation and to calculate obstacle avoidance. It isn't a perfect solution, but I think it's a good starting point.

Comment: Last attempt: why do you need to add points, why do you need to remove some and what is the rationale to make these decisions ?